# The constraint reference 'string' could not be resolved to a type. type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0

Do you know why this error on C# /.NET 6 Web API project? It came suddenly today. Please let me know if you'll need any more info here.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'string' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.DefaultParameterPolicyFactory.Create(RoutePatternParameterPart parameter, String inlineText)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.ParameterPolicyFactory.Create(RoutePatternParameterPart parameter, RoutePatternParameterPolicyReference reference)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.DfaBuilderWorker.AddParentsWithMatchingLiteralConstraints(List`1 nextParents, DfaNode parent, RoutePatternParameterPart parameterPart, IReadOnlyList`1 parameterPolicyReferences)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.DfaBuilderWorker.ProcessSegment(RouteEndpoint endpoint, List`1 parents, List`1 nextParents, RoutePatternPathSegment segment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.DfaBuilderWorker.ProcessLevel(Int32 depth)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.BuildDfaTree(Boolean includeLabel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherBuilder.Build()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DataSourceDependentMatcher.CreateMatcher(IReadOnlyList`1 endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.DataSourceDependentCache`1.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DataSourceDependentMatcher..ctor(EndpointDataSource dataSource, Lifetime lifetime, Func`1 matcherBuilderFactory)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcherFactory.CreateMatcher(EndpointDataSource dataSource)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.InitializeCoreAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatcher|8_0(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task`1 matcherTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: How did you fix this error? Could you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using params in your controller something like this:

[HttpGet("update/{id:string}")] then remove :string.

change it to [HttpGet("update/{id}")].

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue,
constraint type 'string' has not been registered with the RouteOptions.ConstraintMap, which is a dictionary that maps constraint names to constraint types in the application.

Create a class like this:

```
public class StringRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        object value;
        if (values.TryGetValue(routeKey, out value) && value is string)
        {
            // Validate the value of the route parameter here and return true if it is valid
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

after that, go in to ur program.cs and paste this,

```
   services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ConstraintMap.Add("string", typeof(StringRouteConstraint));
    });
```

And your problem should go away :) ,  i named my controller method,

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{id:string}")]
```